# How do I define a field ONCE, then use that definition in multiple entities?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am using class inheritance to add a set of basic fields that all my entities must include. When I do this, EF Core honors any data annotations that exist in the base class, such as `[TimeStamp]`, on the class that is inheriting from it:

```
public class SomeClass : BaseEntity
{
    public string SomeEntityField { get; set; }
}

public class BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset CreatedDate { get; set; }

    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
}
```

The above is great when I want to add all inherited fields.

But, what if I wanted to to be able to create a field definition ONCE, and then use that definition in just a few other entities whilst also inheriting from the base class (above) at the same time?

Lets suppose I have this entity, `ItemType`:

```
public class ItemType : BaseEntity
{
    [StringLength(28)]
    public string ItemTypeId { get; set; }
    ...
```

I'd like to be able to define the field `ItemTypeId` in one place, and then use it on multiple entities including the above table WITHOUT having to manually add/maintain the annotation(s) in all those entities. For example, if I need to make the field wider like `[StringLength(50)]`, I adjust it in one place and then all associated fields are updated on the next migration since they all "read" from the same definition. I've tried

1. using interfaces, but data annotations on interfaces are not honored by EF.
2. multiple inheritance, but that can't be used because I may need multiple "one-off" fields (and interfaces don't work as per #1)

According to [CS1721](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1721?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS1721)) nothing will work (ok, with the exception of the single base class itself).

I think ideally I'd like to be able to define the entity fields in `CommonFieldType` as in the code below, and then have target entities inherit from them, but unfortunately that can't work for the reasons above.

```
namespace RDCApp.Shared.CommonFieldType
{   
    public abstract class ItemTypeIdCFT
    {
        [StringLength(28)]
        public string ItemTypeId { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class AnotherCFT
    {
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string AnotherField { get; set; }
    }

    ...
```

I can't be the only person who needs/would like this so is there another way?

I am aware that the Fluent API could be used, but my project is so invested in data annotations that using that (as well as) feels wrong, and means I have 2 places to look in and define field attributes against. Defining against the POCOs directly just feels right to me!

**EDIT**
To qualify what "feels right to me" means: my VS solution includes both the server (ASP.NET Core) and client side (Blazor WASM) projects. Both tiers can 'see' the entities/POCOs in a shared project and both tiers need to know what the annotations are to perform validation. This means I only need to define validation/attributes once and in turn both tiers have sight of that.

For me, Fluent is not a suitable option - though if this were a typical server side only App I'd shoot for Fluent.

Comment: Try to use Fluent API to override base length constraint: `modelBuilder.Entity<SomeInheritor>().Property(b => b.ItemTypeId).HasMaxLength(100);`

Comment: *"Defining against the POCO's directly just feels right to me"* Well, for many people that feels wrong as it pollutes the model. The truth though is that many things in EF Core can *only* be done with fluent API, so not using them when you can (self limiting in addition to language/framework limitations) doesn't sound smart.

Comment: I figured Fluent would be the general concensus after just having read a few "Fluent vs DA" type convos. Feels like Fluent is great(er) for EF because it can do a few things that DA cannot and like you say, it keeps POCO's cleaner. But because I'm using the same POCOs on the client side (Blazor WebAssembly) its useful to have data annotations since Blazor client can use them too.

Comment: EF doesn't find annotations in interfaces by default but the only reason it finds them in base classes is because its default conventions examine the base classes using reflection. You can plug in your own custom convention

Answer (score 0):

You could define an interface and a generic fluent api helper method to define the fields.

```cs
public interface IHasItemType{
    int ItemTypeId { get; set; }
}
public void DefineItemType<T> (EntityTypeBuilder<T> builder) where T:IHasItemType{
    builder.Property(i => i.ItemTypeId) ...
}
```

Or you could apply conventions in `OnModelCreating`

```cs
foreach (var table in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
{
    foreach (var column in table.GetProperties())
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked fine, thank you. However it wasn't what I needed in the end (see my edit / answer if you're remotely interested!). Sadly SO says I'm not cool enough to upvote your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Fluent API was not suitable for my project need.
Custom annotations would work great for validation logic on both tiers, but unfortunatley DB schema definitions like [StringLength(30)] can't work (or at least I couldn't get to that).

So I landed on a workaround and although I'm not in love with it, it is serviceable for my specific need:

First, I define a particular fields attributes as constants:

```
public class FieldAttributeValues
{
    public const string InventSerialIdComment = "Unique Id of the asset";
    public const int InventSerialIdStringLength = 25;
    public const bool InventSerialIdRequired = true;
    ...
}
```

Then, those constants can be used inside data annotations, for example:

```
public class SpecAttribute : BaseEntity
{
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = FieldAttributeValues.InventSerialIdRequired)]
    [StringLength(FieldAttributeValues.InventSerialIdStringLength)]
    [Comment(FieldAttributeValues.InventSerialIdComment)]
    public string InventSerialId { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

The downside to this approach is that the developer has to consciously check the FieldAttributeValues class for defined values for a particular field (sort of a manual convention process I guess).

The upshot is that the developer isn't implicity forced to use all of the attributes or even the attribute values as defined, since not all entities will always require the same setup across the patch - i.e. [Required(true)] might generally hold true for most entities, but not some other edge case entity.